# Could not deduce (Ord a0) arising from a use of ‘>’

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am getting compile-time errors related to typeclasses that I'm trying to create.

My program:

```
main = print "here"


class Tiger a where
  tigerWeight :: (Ord o) => a -> o

class Zoo a where
  tiger :: (Tiger t) => a -> t
  tigerHeavier :: a -> a -> Bool
  tigerHeavier x y =
    (tigerWeight (tiger x)) > (tigerWeight (tiger y))
```

gives compile errors:

```
$ ghc zoo
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( zoo.hs, zoo.o )

zoo.hs:14:5: error:
    • Could not deduce (Ord a0) arising from a use of ‘>’
      from the context: Zoo a
        bound by the class declaration for ‘Zoo’ at zoo.hs:(10,1)-(14,53)
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance Ord Integer
          -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type’
        instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression:
        (tigerWeight (tiger x)) > (tigerWeight (tiger y))
      In an equation for ‘tigerHeavier’:
          tigerHeavier x y
            = (tigerWeight (tiger x)) > (tigerWeight (tiger y))

zoo.hs:14:6: error:
    • Could not deduce (Tiger a1) arising from a use of ‘tigerWeight’
      from the context: Zoo a
        bound by the class declaration for ‘Zoo’ at zoo.hs:(10,1)-(14,53)
      The type variable ‘a1’ is ambiguous
    • In the first argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘(tigerWeight (tiger x))’
      In the expression:
        (tigerWeight (tiger x)) > (tigerWeight (tiger y))
      In an equation for ‘tigerHeavier’:
          tigerHeavier x y
            = (tigerWeight (tiger x)) > (tigerWeight (tiger y))

zoo.hs:14:32: error:
    • Could not deduce (Tiger a2) arising from a use of ‘tigerWeight’
      from the context: Zoo a
        bound by the class declaration for ‘Zoo’ at zoo.hs:(10,1)-(14,53)
      The type variable ‘a2’ is ambiguous
    • In the second argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘(tigerWeight (tiger y))’
      In the expression:
        (tigerWeight (tiger x)) > (tigerWeight (tiger y))
      In an equation for ‘tigerHeavier’:
          tigerHeavier x y
            = (tigerWeight (tiger x)) > (tigerWeight (tiger y))
```

Why is this? It seems that all the types should be deducible. In particular:

- 'x' and 'y' are in the Zoo typeclass, and therefore should support the 'tiger' method.
- (tiger x) is in the 'Tiger' typeclass, as marked by the 'tiger' method's signature.
- (tigerWeight (tiger x)) therefore should be able to be applied, and is known to be a member of the 'Ord' class, as marked by the 'tigerWeight' method's signature.

Comment: You have only defined classes, not instances of them.

Comment: Right, does a typeclass need an instance defined in order to compile?

Comment: You seen to confuse haskell typeclasses with classes from OOP world. Typeclasses can be approximated to interfaces, not classes. So yes, you need to have some datatypes to be part of your typeclass (like interface should have classes that implement it).

Comment: Yet another quantification problem: `tigerWeight :: (Ord o) => a -> o` means that the type `o` is chosen by the _caller_, not by the function. This function is promising to convert a tiger (precisely, any type in the `Tiger` class) into any of these types `Bool, [String], [(Int,Char)], ...` -- indeed, any type which is ordered. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 'x' and 'y' are in the Zoo typeclass, and therefore should support the 'tiger' method

They do, but it's not known *which* inhabitant of the `Tiger` typeclass you want. If we look at the `tiger`'s complete type signature,

```
tiger :: (Zoo a, Tiger t) => a -> t
```

we can see that `a` will be deduced by the argument you give `tiger`, but what will `t` be? There needs to be a specific instance (which you don't have), and it needs to be unambiguous.

> (tiger x) is in the 'Tiger' typeclass, as marked by the 'tiger' method's signature.

Again, there is no instance of `Tiger`. Or, to speak with OO terms, there is only the interface, but not something that implements that interface.

> (tigerWeight (tiger x)) therefore should be able to be applied, and is known to be a member of the 'Ord' class, as marked by the 'tigerWeight' method's signature.

The `Ord` typeclass is rather large. You have to specify *which* instance you want. It's not clear, which one you want, since all of them support `>`.

Compare that to `read :: (Read a) => String -> a`. As long as you don't specify the `a`, it's not clear how the string should get parsed.

```
read "1" :: Int
```

will work, but

```
read "1" :: [Int]
```

should fail. That choice needs to be done.

By the way, there is no sensilbe way to write `tiger :: Ord a => a -> o` since you cannot create arbitrary `Ord` values.

---

That being said, you're approaching that problem from the wrong side. A `Tiger` is a very specific animal. There is no need for a `typeclass`:

```
data Tiger = ...
```

Afterwards, you can write a completely normal function that returns the actual weight:

```
type Weight = Int

tigerWeight :: Tiger -> Weight
tigerWeight t = ...

data Zoo = ...

tiger :: Zoo -> Tiger
```